Azure DevOps yaml file to run pipeline in Azure Synapse Analytics
I am working on Azure DevOps and Azure Synapse Analytics. Right now, I have the issue to integration Azure DevOps with Azure Synpase Analytics together. How could I use the yaml file and azure powershell in azure DevOps together to activate the pipeline in azure synapse analytics or how to launch the pipeline in azure synapse via Azure DevOps yaml file?
update: could you provide me how to use the service connection and how to implement a powershell script in azure DevOps instead of using a incline script in the YAML pipeline definition.

Hi @Joanmok, Thanks for the update. May I know if you are the owner of the Azure subscription where the Azure Synapse Analytics resource is created, or what RBAC role to the subscription and the resource scope is assigned for your user account? Do you have the permission to create a new service principle (app registration) in Microsoft Entra (formerly Azure Active Directory) or do you have the permission to add credential for the app? The information may help select the method to create an new ARM service connection used in AzurePowerShell pipeline task.

Hi @Alvin Zhao, i am not the owner of the azure subscription, but i am the owner of the resource group. I am asking the owner to create a new service principle (app registration) in Microsoft Entra and grant the new service principle permission to the azure synapse analytics.

Hi @Joanmok, Thanks for your update. Please find my latest answer to help your manually create a new ARM service connection. Hope it works for you as well and can resolve your query in this post. Appreciate your efforts.

Update
Based on the discussions and updates, let's assume you have got a service principal (app registration) and granted it with the Synapse Administrator role in your Azure Synapse workspace like below.

We can proceed to manually create a new Azure Resource Manager service connection in Azure DevOps for the AzurePowerShell pipeline task to authenticate against this service principal with Workload identity federation authentication, which can avoid client secret leakage or issue caused by its expiration. Here are the brief steps for your reference.

In Azure Portal. navigate to Microsoft Entra Id (formerly Azure Active Directory) -> App registrations -> Select the app for authentication -> Keep note of the Application (client) ID and Directory (tenant) ID;


In Azure Portal, collect your Subscription ID and name; Go to the resource group where your Azure Synapse workspace resource locates -> As the resource group Owner, you should be able to assign the app with the Contributor role to the scope of this resource group (this RBAC role assignment is for ARM service connection validation; the permission may not be minimum but is the same role assignment during an automated ARM service connection creation);



In Azure DevOps, browse to your Project Settings -> Pipelines -> Service connections -> New service connection -> Select the type of Azure Resource Manager -> Select Workload Identity federation (manual) -> Give a name for the ARM service connection;


Keep note of the Issuer and Subject identifier -> Input the Subscription Id, Subscription Name, Service Principal Id and Tenant ID from step 1 & 2; you can save the new ARM service connection as a draft now and move on to next step;


In Azure Portal again, Select the app -> Click on Certificates & secrets blade -> Click on Federated credentials tab -> Add credential -> Select Other issuer and Input the Issuer and Subject identifier from step 4;


Go back to Azure DevOps ARM service connection draft to Finish setup -> Click on the Verify and save button;



Per the requirement not to use the inline script in YAML pipeline definition, you may add a .ps1 script file with the sample command below in your repo first. In your Azure DevOps YAML pipeline definition file, you can reference the new ARM service connection by its name in the AzurePowerShell pipeline task and run the script file with FilePath.
Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline.ps1
Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline -WorkspaceName "$env:MY_WORKSPACE" -PipelineName "$env:PIPELINE_NAME"


azure-pipeline.yml
variables:
  myWorkspace: azsynapsexxxxxx0
  pipelineName: Pipeline 1

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMSvcCnnAzureSynapseResource0'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: 'Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline.ps1'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
  env:
    MY_WORKSPACE: $(myWorkspace)
    PIPELINE_NAME: $(pipelineName)



According to this document on Pipeline execution and triggers - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse, you may test to run the Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline Azure PowerShell command in the AzurePowerShell@5 DevOps pipeline task to trigger your Azure Synapse pipeline.
Here is my sample YAML Azure DevOps pipeline for your reference.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFAutoSub1'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline -WorkspaceName $(myWorkspace) -PipelineName "Pipeline 1"
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'


If you already created an Azure Resource Manager service connection in Azure DevOps, please make sure its underly service principle that the Azure DevOps pipeline authenticates against is granted with sufficient permission to trigger Azure Synapse pipeline.


Hi Alvin, thaks for the reply. I have two questions. 1. Is it necessary to create an Azure Resource Manager service connection to launch the pipeline in azure synapse? 2. I don't want to write the Powershell Script inside of the yaml file. How could I make it separately but include it in my yaml file? Many thanks.

The ARM service connection is used to store the service principal information (including the authentication method/info like client secret), so that the AzurePowerShell task can run Connect-AzAccount at the very beginning of the script, which is the prerequisite command to be run before Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline and can avoid secret leakage or expiration if you are using the workload identity federation authentication. Still, NO. It is not necessary to use the ARM service connection or the AzurePowerShell task, if you can add that authentication command in your script.

Per your second question, may I assume you would prefer to push a script .ps1 file in your repo and execute that script? It is also possible to use the script path instead of a inline script.

Hi @Joanmok, As for the actual requirements, so you don't want to use ARM service connection nor a incline script in the YAML pipeline definition, do you? Or can you edit your original post with the details? I can proceed to update my answer.

Hi @Alvin, I updated my post with details. Could you help me on that? I would like to do the set up for service connection and also a separate powershell script to launch the pipeline in my azure synpase via azure DevOps.

Hi Alvin, thanks a lot. Could you also explain release in azure devops? Why do we need to use release in azure devops, instead of using pipeline for the post deployment? Thanks in advance.

Hi @Joanmok, May I know if my updated answer to use the Invoke-AzSynapsePipeline command in a script file can resolve your query in this post? Kindly don't include multiple questions in one, otherwise this thread may be closed due to lack of focus. Please feel welcome to post a new query and engage the insights from the experts in our community. Thx for your sharing.

Hi @Alvin Zhao, that is really helpful and resolve my query. Thanks again.
